# Form Re-Submission Deletes Next GridView Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `Gridview` and the `OnRowDeleting` method with removes a record from the database and the gridview.
My problem is that when a user click the delete button in the `Gridview` the record will be removed from the database but the `GridView` does not show this update (does not refresh). If the user then refreshes the page causing a form re-submission then the `GridView` deletes the row below the originally deleted row and so on if the page is refreshed again.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvShowQuestionnaires" HeaderStyle-CssClass="table_header" CssClass="view" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#f3f4f8" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames='QuestionnaireID' OnRowDeleting="gvShowQuestionnaires_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvShowQuestionnaires_RowEdit" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvShowQuestionnaires_SelectedIndexChanged" FooterStyle-CssClass="view_table_footer" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionnaireID" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-CssClass="bo"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionnaireName" HeaderText="Questionnaire Name" />           
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="select" ButtonType="Link" Text="hello" />
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Options" CausesValidation="true" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit">
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the OnRowDeleting method.

```
protected void gvShowQuestionnaires_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int questionnaireID = (int)gvShowQuestionnaires.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex)].Value;
    GetData.DeleteQuestionnaire(questionnaireID); // Deletes Questionniare from database
    gvShowQuestionnaires.DataSource = DT;
    gvShowQuestionnaires.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always redirect the user to the initial page after the row was deleted, e.g. in the RowDeleted handler.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

This should work because the delete action is a POST command to the current .aspx page.

Comment: Yes this does work. However one small thing. I have an asp:label that display when the delete method is fired. However redirecting the page does not show the delete confirmation label? How can I show the label on page reload only when the delete method is fired?

Comment: Add an URL parameter to the page, than look for that parameter in the page load method and enable the label if the URL parameter was present.